# Why Yii PrimaryKey of model is null?

Tags: php, model, primary-key, yii

I have a table in my database and worked this by yii model and this table had not primarykey and id column.

Then i decide to add an id column to this table. When added an id column as primaryKey my model cannot find this new column as primaryKey and when i called $this->primaryKey in my model, return null to me!

Comment: Did you delete your previous model and use gii to generate the model code all over again?

Comment: you have to generate your model again to be sure you made it right (make a backup before the procedure)

Comment: try to clear the cash by clearing runtime folder for example.

Comment: when i delete model and table and create a new model with new name and create new table this work! why?

Answer (score 0):

You should add your new attribute in the "attributeLabels" method.

```
 public function attributeLabels() {
        return array(
            'id_table' => 'Id Table',
                  ...
        );
    }
```

Furthermore, You could use Gii to generate your new model.

Comment: Please edit your question with your model and controller, thanks.